# Weak* limit of ergodic measures

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

I'm working through problem 4.1.2 of Einsidler and Ward's *Ergodic Theory with a view towards number theory", which asks to show that the weak* limit of ergodic measures need not be ergodic using the following scheme:

Let $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots)\in 2^\mathbb{N}$ (with $2=\{0,1\}$) be a binary sequence such that every block of $k$ digits appears in it with asymptotic frequency $2^{-k}$. Such an $x$ exists by the pointwise ergodic theorem.

Define $y_n\in 2^\mathbb{Z}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ by the conditions:

- $y_n|_{[0,2n-1]}=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n,0,0,\dots,0)$ ($n$ $0$s).
- $\sigma^{2n}(y_n)=y_n$

where $\sigma:2^\mathbb{Z}\to 2^\mathbb{Z}$ is the two-sided left shift. It is clear that $y_n\to y$ in the product topology, where $y$ is defined by
$$ y(k)=
\begin{cases}
x_{k+1} & k\ge 0\\
0 & k<0
\end{cases}
$$
since $y_n$ and $y$ agree on $[-n,n]$.

We construct probability measures supported on the orbit of $y_n$ under $\sigma$:
$$\mu_n:=\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}\delta_{\sigma^k y_n}$$
where $\delta_z$ denotes the Dirac delta concentrated at $z$. Further, let $\nu:=\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}\delta_{\sigma^k y}$.

I'd like to show that $\mu_n\to \nu$ in the weak* topology. Letting $f\in C(2^\mathbb{Z})$, we have that:

$$\mu_n(f)-\nu(f)=\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}f(\sigma^ky_n)-f(\sigma^k y)$$
which looks like it should tend to $0$ as $n\to \infty$, but I'm stuck in giving a proof. I can bound $d(\sigma^k y_n,\sigma^k y)\le \frac{1}{n+1-k}$ where $d$ is the standard metric on $2^\mathbb{Z}$ (defined by $d(x,y)=\inf \{1/(k+1): x(i)=y(i)\ \forall |i|\le k\}$), but couldn't get much further.

Comment: Hint: it does not converge to $\nu$.

Comment: @JohnB thank you for your help. Could you be more specific? I'm having trouble seeing what it converges too.

Comment: That's a more difficult matter. I suggest that you start by considering the continuous functions that are characteristics of cylinders (well chosen cylinders!).

Comment: @JohnB I know realize that my definition of $\nu$ makes no sense since I wanted to take the limit as $n\to \infty$. I had a look at this answer on MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23443/on-the-convergence-of-ergodic-measures, there's a similar measure with is stated to converge to a convex combination of Dirac deltas (which I'm also not seeing). A question, can the characteristic function of a cylinder be continuous?

Comment: That's what I hinted to: for sure by considering certain cylinders you will see that you get the two deltas. Sure, all characteristic functions of cylinders are continuous (simple exercise).

Comment: @JohnB Characteristics are continuous since cylinders are clopen, that was silly of me. Sorry for being annoying, but I'm not sure which cylinders I should be considering to get that the sum converges to the two deltas.

Comment: Now you need to think a bit more for yourself.

Comment: It doesn't make sense when you write $\mu_n(f)$. It is plausible to evaluate any continuous function $f$ under the integration by $\mu_n$ in order to show that the Borel probability measures on the metric space converges.